# How do I set up Vim to compile using Visual Studio 2010's C++ compiler?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, vim

I can compile from the command line by running **vcvarsall.bat**, then running **cl.exe** with my source file as the only argument. The problem is that just running **cl.exe** without first setting up the environment using the aforementioned batch file causes errors due to "missing libraries".

I can picture a couple of workarounds to this, for example creating a batch file in my project directory that includes **vcvarsall.bat** and does all the compiling. That seems to me to be a very cumbersome and inflexible solution though. I would much prefer to be able to compile and run any C or C++ file from Vim like one would in Unix:

```
:nnorebind <F5> :! g++ %<CR>
```

I don't want to add the pile of paths that **vcvarsall.bat** adds to the environment permanently though. I don't know how to phrase my question any better than this: How do I set up Vim to be able to use the Visual Studio 2010 C++ compiler?

Comment: Could you write your own script that calls the vcvars to load the variables and then calls the compiler? Alternatively, you can run vcvars and run vim inside the shell...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can update environment variables from within Vim. For instance, to add "c:\foo" to the start of your PATH:

```
let $PATH='c:\\foo;'.$PATH
```

I copied the relevant portions of my vcvars*.bat file to my vimrc:

```
if !exists("visual_studio_paths_added")
    let visual_studio_paths_added = 1
    let $PATH="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\Common7\\IDE;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\BIN;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\Common7\\Tools;C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v3.5;C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\VCPackages;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v6.0A\\bin;".$PATH
    let $INCLUDE="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\ATLMFC\\INCLUDE;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\INCLUDE;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v6.0A\\include;".$INCLUDE
    let $LIB="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\ATLMFC\\LIB;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\LIB;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v6.0A\\lib;".$LIB
    let $LIBPATH="C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v3.5;C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\ATLMFC\\LIB;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\LIB;".$LIBPATH
endif
```

Adapt as needed given your version of Visual Studio and installation directory.

In my case, I put this in a function. I call `:vcvars` when I want to work with Visual Studio. But you could just have those changes always included.

Comment: Do these changes have to be global to Vim, or could they be set on a buffer-to-buffer basis?

Comment: They change the *environment* of the Vim process, so yes, they are global.

Comment: Wow, this is so much simpler than what I was doing running vcvars, diff-ing before and after, and trying to parse the results in a script...

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the comment by David Rodríguez - dribeas, and seeing how `vcvarsall.bat` accepts parameters, I found it helpful to have the following file in my source trees:

`vc.bat`:

```
call "%VS100COMNTOOLS%\..\..\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64 & %*
```

Adjust MSVS version and platform as appropriate, or make them additional parameters if you like. The `%VS...COMNTOOLS%` environment variable is set by the MSVC installer, which makes the above independent of the actual installation path.

This allows me to run any `<command>` in the proper MSVC environment by running it as:

```
vc.bat <command>
```

If called without parameters, it will just set the environment for the current shell without executing any further commands.

If you want to go one step further, there is [CMake](http://www.cmake.org), a meta-buildsystem that allows you to generate Unix Makefiles, MSVC solutions and several other buildfile types from a single (CMake syntax) configuration. One of the buildfile types supported on Windows are *NMake Makefiles*... and `nmake <target>` on Windows handles just about as well as `make <target>` does on Unix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plugin [vcvars.vim](https://github.com/hattya/vcvars.vim) to set up environment variables.

In Neovim, using lazy.nvim as package manager, one can set up environment variables with vcvars.vim by

```lua
    {
        "hattya/vcvars.vim",
        event = "VeryLazy",
        config = function()
            vim.cmd([[
            let vcvars_dict = vcvars#get(vcvars#list()[-1])
            let $PATH = join(vcvars_dict.path, ';') .';'. $PATH
            let $INCLUDE = join(vcvars_dict.include, ';') .';'. $INCLUDE
            let $LIB = join(vcvars_dict.lib, ';') .';'. $LIB
            let $LIBPATH = join(vcvars_dict.libpath, ';') .';'. $LIBPATH
            ]])
        end,
    },
```

Answer (score -1):

Mud's solution did not work for me with Visual Studio 2017 Community. Paths are different. I think DevSolar's way to use vcvarsall.bat is more reliable, as it lets VS take care of the correct paths.

As I don't want to carry around a .bat file with my vim config, I was looking for a solution to work only inside the .vimrc:

1. Add vcvarsall.bat to your PATH. In my case `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC`.
2. Put the following in your .vimrc to compile current file by F8

   `nnoremap <F8> :!vcvarsall.bat && cl /EHsc % <CR>`

Comment: **"Mud's solution did not work for me with Visual Studio 2017 Community. Paths are different."**

That's what I mean by "Adapt as needed given **your version of Visual Studio and installation directory**."

Obviously using vcvars.bat works, but running that from Vim won't alter Vim's environment. My approach is showing how to alter Vim's environment without having to restart Vim. Your approach also works, but that doesn't work with Vim's `:make` command nor does it let you execute arbitrary VS tools without prepending every command with that bat. I'd rather just update Vim's environment.